# Escape HTML dentro do elemento <code> - Sem jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite. Estou desenvolvendo um chat e estou quebrando a cabeça aqui em uma parte. Eu capturo o texto, trato ele, verifico o que é img ou link e apenas coloco dentro das tags `<img>` e `<a>`, respectivamente. Caso não seja um link, uma imagem ou texto, eu encapsulo com `<code>`. Então o resultado acaba ficando assim, por exemplo:

`let msg = "Olá, meu nome é josé. Você já viu esse site <a href="www.g1.com">g1</a>? Lá tem a imagem <img src="teste.jpg">. Podemos usa-lá dentro da <pre><code><div><p>teste</p></div></code></pre>. O que acha?;`

E minha dúvida é: Como eu pego tudo que está ai dentro da tag **CODE** dando o famoso escape no html? O resultado final deveria ficar assim, creio eu:

`let msg = "Olá, meu nome é josé. Você já viu esse site <a href="www.g1.com">g1</a>? Lá tem a imagem <img src="teste.jpg">. Podemos usa-lá dentro da <pre><code> &lt;div&gt; &lt;p&gt; teste &lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt; </code></pre>. O que acha?;`

Obrigado

Comment: Voce usa jquery?

Comment: Não. Js Puro, amigo.

Comment: Então vai ser difícil tua sina, já aviso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma usando alguns métodos para encontrar os trechos dentro de `<code></code>` e fazer as substituições (explicações no código):

```js
let msg = 'Olá, meu nome é josé. Você já viu esse site <a href="www.g1.com">g1</a>? Lá tem a imagem <img src="teste.jpg">. Podemos usa-lá dentro da <pre><code><div><p>teste</p></div></code></pre> <pre><code><div><p>teste2</p></div></code></pre>. O que acha?';
msg.match(/<code>(.*?)<\/code>/g) // pego onde tem <code></code> criando uma array
.map(a =>{
   a = a.replace(/<code>|<\/code>/gi, ''); // elimino <code> e </code>
   let re = new RegExp(a, 'g'); // regex para capturar os valores de cada índice da array
   let rep = a.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); // substituir as ocorrências
   msg = msg.replace(re, rep); // atualiza a string msg
});

console.log(msg);
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = msg;
```

Comment: Exatamente isso. Obrigado, DVD!

Comment: Obg! Refiz o código, ficou bem mais simples agora. Atualiza aí. Abs!

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, DVD!

Answer (score 0):

Use isto:

```
function escapeHTML(str)
{
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   var text = document.createTextNode(str);
   div.appendChild(text);
   return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://forums.asp.net/t/1151879.aspx?HttpUtility+HtmlEncode+in+javaScript+)